# Jupyter Lab - Kite is installed but its not working

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, kite

i've been trying to install Kite in JupyterLab v2.2.6. I have dowloaded and installed Kite, have node.js 15.0.1 and i've run the console commands:

```
pip install jupyter-kite
jupyter labextension install "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite"
```

i have no problems with either and when i check in jupyter extension manager it tells me that it is installed

[Kite missing some dependencies error message in jupyterlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkg6f.png)

Comment: Do you have the console/error you get when you try to use it?

Comment: No @Halmon, i get no errors at all, just a message inside jupyter that tells me that "kite is missing some dependencies". I have updated the post with the message

Comment: apparently not all versions of jupyter-lab work with kite. see https://github.com/kiteco/issue-tracker/issues/532#issuecomment-843942181

Answer (score 2):

Update for macOS Catalina users, try upgrading JupyterLab > 2.2.9:

1. Open Terminal:

   ```
   $ conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3.0.3
   ```
2. Open Kite copilot:

   ```
   -->
   Home
   -->
   Redo Setup
   ```
3. Open Terminal:

   ```
   $ pip install "jupyterlab-kite>=2.0.2"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

As of this post, Kite works with:
[jupyterlab 3.2.7](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab/3.2.7/)
[jupyterlab-kite 2.0.2](https://pypi.org/project/jupyterlab-kite/2.0.2/)

JupyterLab:
`conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab=3.2.7`
or
`pip install jupyterlab==3.2.7`

Kite:
`pip install jupyterlab-kite>=2.0.2` (only PyPI)
`jupyter labextension install "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite"`

Note also that as of this post, there is no Kite extension for VS Code that is compatible with `.ipynb`. The VS Code Kite extension is [compatible](https://help.kite.com/article/125-troubleshooting-the-vs-code-plugin) with  `.py`  `.go`  `.js`  `.jsx`  `.vue` only.

In addition, you can no longer download the Kite engine from the Kite website.

Adam has posted the installers [here](https://github.com/kiteco/kiteco-public/releases/tag/2021-06-10).
[macOS](https://github.com/kiteco/kiteco-public/releases/download/2021-06-10/Kite.dmg)
[Windows](https://github.com/kiteco/kiteco-public/releases/download/2021-06-10/KiteSetup.exe)
[Linux](https://github.com/kiteco/kiteco-public/releases/download/2021-06-10/kite-installer.sh)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and for me the following worked:

Reinstalled Anaconda and then I updated the provided JupyterLab version in the (base) terminal. (You would like to update your JupyterLab in the respective virtual environment you are using Anaconda with.)

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab==2.2.9
```

The JupyterLab version in your Anaconda should show 2.2.9 after you restart Anaconda. After this, download node.js and install it on you computer. Then follow the instructions in your Kite desktop app to install the Jupyter Kite extension via the (base) terminal:

```
pip install jupyter-kite
jupyter labextension install "@kiteco/jupyterlab-kite"
```

Open your Kite desktop app and click on <kbd>Redo Setup</kbd> under the <kbd>Home</kbd> section.

In your JupyterLab Kite: *Initializing* should appear down in the left corner.

Comment: Ok... it says initializing.  And nothing else, ever.  So that's terrible.  How do I make it actually work?

Comment: A work around for this might be to install Kite and Jupyter Notebook as VSCode extensions. I moved my data science projects to this IDE and here everything works fine.